# derivative interpretation: "decreasing rate" vs "rate is decreasing"

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is saying "decreasing rate" the same as saying "rate is decreasing"?

I'm a AP calculus teacher grading a question that ask about the interpretation of the derivative of a rate. The answer key answer says,
"...the rate of filling bottles is decreasing at a rate of 5.164 gal. per min. per min."

Someone wrote,
"..the bottles are being filled at a decreasing rate of 5.164..."

I'm not 100% sure if that is logically equivalent to the correct answer.

Is saying, "rate of change is decreasing "  logically equivalent to saying, "[filled] at a decreasing rate"??

Comment: I'd be curious to hear the rest of their sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes "Rate of change is decreasing" IS logically equivalent to a "decreasing rate" which is equivalent to saying in this case that
$\frac{d^2V}{dt^2}=-5.164$.